# In SpecFlow can you store more than one hook in the same steps file

Tags: c#, specflow

In the c# bindings for specflow. 
Can you store more than one hook in the same file?

For example I'm thinking about keep a few hooks together like this

```
[AfterScenario("hook_afterscenario_x_cleanup")]
public void AfterScenario()
{
  //do x
}
[AfterScenario("hook_afterscenario_y_cleanup")]
public void AfterScenario()
{
  //do y
}
```

If not why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is fine, just don't call the methods the same thing:

```
[AfterScenario("hook_afterscenario_x_cleanup")]
public void AfterScenarioX()
{
  //do x
}

[AfterScenario("hook_afterscenario_y_cleanup")]
public void AfterScenarioY()
{
  //do y
}
```

having two methods with the same name and same arguments in the same class is not valid in c#, which is why your example does not compile

Comment: AfterScenario for specflow is a function that's ran after each scenario finishing. So I'm not sure if you can change the name like that. Have you tried it with specflow? will it still run after the scenarios? Or are you more saying the c# language bindings get in the way here.

Comment: The method names don't matter to specflow. What it cares about is the attribute. So you can call the methods whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks, its much clearer to me now. The scope page in Specflows github helped expand my understanding too.